# Make a payment via stripe in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, stripe-payments

I want to make a "payment" type form, because the "card" does not fit because it is in one line. I'm trying to get data from a form, create a token to make a payment. But I get the error "You cannot create a charge with a PaymentMethod. Use the Payment Intents API instead.; request-id: req_9AYqRwPYg7MPdU". How can it be solved? Thank you.

```
<form id="payment-form" method="post">
   <input id="api-key" type="hidden" value="${stripePublicKey}">
   <div class="form-group mb-3">
       <div class="w-100" id="card-element">
           <!-- A Stripe Element will be inserted here. -->
       </div>
   </div>
   <button class="btn w-100 btn-success mt-4" type="submit" id="submitButton">Pay $230</button>
</form>
<script>
    const stripe = Stripe($('#api-key').val());
    const payment = stripe.elements({clientSecret:'${client_secret}'}).create('payment');
    payment.mount('#card-element');

    payment.addEventListener('change', function (event) {
        $('#card-errors').text(event.error ? event.error.message : '');
    });

    $('#payment-form').on('submit', async function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        const { paymentMethod, error } = await stripe.createPaymentMethod(
            'payment',
            payment,
            { billing_details: { email: '${customer.email}' } }
        );
        if (error) {
            alert(error);
        } else {
            const token = paymentMethod.id;
            const email = '${customer.email}';
            $.post(
                "/payment/create-charge",
                {email: email, token: token},
                function (data) {
                    alert(data.details);
                }, 'json');
        }
    });
</script>
```

```
@PostMapping("/create-charge")
public @ResponseBody StripeResponse createCharge(String email, String token) {
    if (token == null) {
        return new StripeResponse(false, "Stripe payment token is missing. please try again later.");
    }
    String chargeId = stripeService.createCharge(email, token, 999);// 9.99 usd
    if (chargeId == null) {
        return new StripeResponse(false, "An error accurred while trying to charge.");
    }
    return new StripeResponse(true, "Success your charge id is " + chargeId);
}
```

```
@Override
public String createCharge(String email, String token, int amount) {
    String chargeId = null;
    try {
        Stripe.apiKey = API_SECRET_KEY;
        Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<>();
        chargeParams.put("description", "Charge for " + email);
        chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
        chargeParams.put("amount", amount);
        chargeParams.put("source", token);
        Charge charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
        chargeId = charge.getId();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return chargeId;
}
```

I was trying to get a token with this code, it was going into the catch block and returning "{ }" to the console

```
stripe.createToken(payment).then((result) => {
    // The code does not go here
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error(error); // Displays "{ }" in console
});
```

Comment: The error is very clear.  You are creating a PaymentMethod.  That is the wrong thing.  You need to create a PaymentIntent.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to create payment intent and once you generate payment intent you will get a **client_secrete** in the response, this means your payment is ready for the attempt of collecting payment you can have option of setting use client SDK to true or false.

```
Stripe.apiKey = "your_stripe_secrete_key";

List<Object> paymentMethodTypes =
  new ArrayList<>();
paymentMethodTypes.add("card");
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("amount", whatever_amount_you_want_to_charge);
params.put("currency", "currency_abv" //ex- usd, inr, aud, etc);
params.put(
  "payment_method_types",
  paymentMethodTypes
);

PaymentIntent paymentIntent =
  PaymentIntent.create(params);
```

Here you have to perform another operation called confirming that payment intent earlier you have created, obliviously it has all the information so you just have to specify payment method, authenticate and confirm payment intent (before confirming stripe provides options to modify that payment intent).

**From backend**

```
Stripe.apiKey = "your_stripe_secrete_key";


PaymentIntent paymentIntent =
  PaymentIntent.retrieve(
    "payment_intent_id"
  );

Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<>();
params.put("payment_method", "pm_card_visa");

PaymentIntent updatedPaymentIntent =
  paymentIntent.confirm(params);
```

**From frontend**

```
stripe
  .confirmCardPayment('{PAYMENT_INTENT_CLIENT_SECRET}', {
    payment_method: {
      card: cardElement,
      billing_details: {
        name: 'name',
      },
    },
  })
  .then(function(result) {
    // Handle result.error or result.paymentIntent
  });
```

Stripe will use client SDK and your client secrete which you have earlier generated from payment intent to make a payment so this will try to collect payment, remember if you are using any 3D secured card to make payment you have confirm that payment using OTP or any authentication provided by respective bank or else your payment intent will go in the mode of **require_confirmation** state

**For reference**

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/create#create_payment_intent

https://stripe.com/docs/js/payment_intents/payment_method#confirm_payment_intent_payment_method

https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/confirm#confirm_payment_intent

Comment: The frontend returns an error "IntegrationError: Invalid value for confirmCardPayment: payment_method.card was \`payment\` Element, which cannot be used to create card PaymentMethods."

Comment: you need to add element there and make a reference of that element as a card, please check out this https://github.com/stripe-archive/react-stripe-elements#setting-up-your-payment-form-injectstripe